correct tense: [believed that your answer was] or [believe that your answer was]
I have made up the sentences below.

I think the way they explained the theory made sense but it wasn't totally correct. Based on their logic, they believed that your answer was wrong. However, I'm sure you are correct.
I think the way they explained the theory made sense but it wasn't totally correct. Based on their logic, they believe that your answer was wrong. However, I'm sure you are correct.

My non-native friends think the present tense of "believe" is correct. I don't understand why. Thanks for your help.

Does this answer your question? Always past tense when telling someone's history? Also Do you know what they mean/meant by this? and tense in a sub-clause, among others.

If you say, "they believed", that means that they believed this at some time in the past. They may or may not still believe it today.
If you say, "they believe", you mean that they believe it today.
Sometimes the time frame is very significant. Like if I said, "Five years ago I believed that my wife loved me, but today I do not", the past tense is very pointed and relevant.
In this example, it probably doesn't make much difference. At the time that "they" explained their theory, they believed that your answer was wrong. Have their views changed since then? Maybe and maybe not, but it's probably not relevant.
DavidK makes a tangential point that the paragraph is perhaps puzzling, because, at least without any further context, there is no indication that "they" ever heard "your answer", so how could they either believe it or not believe it? What I THINK the writer is saying is that, based on "their" theory, if they had heard your answer, they would not have believed it. If that's what is meant, you should say, "Based on their logic, THEY WOULD believe your answer is wrong."

At the end of this answer, you write the sentence exactly the say I do, word for word, based on what you think the writer is saying. So we both agree on that point. I also believe that writing a passage in such a way that it communicates the meaning you want to communicate is essential to correct writing, and that addressing what we think the author is trying to say is more than a "tangential point."

@DavidK Fair enough.

Neither version of the passage makes sense to me.
To believe something, you must have accepted the belief in that thing.
In order to accept the belief, you must think of it or hear of it.
To believe that an idea is wrong, you must first encounter the idea somehow.
In your passage, "they" explained a theory incorrectly. "You" had a different answer that contradicts that explanation. But there's no suggestion in the passage that "they" have ever thought of or heard of "your" answer.
Instead, it is the speaker or writer of this passage who considers "your" answer in the light of "their" logic.
It is possible that additional context (consisting of previous statements) could tell us that "they" indeed did consider "your" answer but nevertheless gave a contradictory explanation. In that case sentence (1) makes a statement about the belief "they" had at some past time to which the additional context refers.
Sentence (2) would state that "they" were aware of "your" answer in the past, but that "they" now believe the answer is wrong.
Without additional context, however, neither interpretation seems likely to me. The most likely interpretation is that "they" have neither thought of nor heard of "your" answer.
The passage therefore should be,
(3) I think the way they explained the theory made sense but it wasn't totally correct. Based on their logic, they would believe that your answer is wrong. However, I'm sure you are correct.
